# Issue accessing Auth() object data in Laravel class

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I am seeing some behaviour. I can't explain when accessing user data via the `Auth` facade in Laravel class. Here's an extract of my code:

```
private $data;
private $userID;//Set property

function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');//Call middleware
    $this->userID = Auth::id();//Define property as user ID
}

public function index() {
    return view('');
}

public function MyTestMethod() {

    echo $this->userID;//This returns null
    echo Auth::id();//This works & returns the current user ID

}
```

I am logged in and have included `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` in the class thus the code works, but only when accessing `Auth` in methods - else it returns a `null` value.

Most odd, I can't work out what is causing this. Any thoughts much appreciated as ever. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now, after upgrading to Laravel 5.3,Auth::user() returns null when being called from the controller's constructor.   check this : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-call-authuser-on-controllers-constructor

Comment: Wow the speed of responses on here is amazing! Thank you all.. let me have a read and try the suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Laravel 5.3.4 or above, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor, since the middlware isn't runnig yet.

As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor.:

try this :

```
function __construct()
{    
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
       if (!auth()->check()) {
          return redirect('/login');
       }

       $this->userID = auth()->id(); // or auth()->user()->id

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

another alternative solution go you your base controller class and add `__get` function like this :

```
class Controller
{
    public function __get(string $name)
    {
        if($name === 'user'){
            return Auth::user();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and now if your current controller you can use it like this `$this->user`:

```
class YourController extends Controller 
{
    public function MyTestMethod() {
        echo $this->user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help here - I'm afraid none of the suggested solutions worked. I'm on version 5.4.32 so this will be the cause.  have also tried: '    public function 

`MyMethod(Request $request) {

        $userID = $request->user();
       
        echo $userID;
     
    }`

 but doesn't work and defeats point as in the method. I get Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\RecommendingService::RecommendByPersonal() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

Comment: MyMethod() { $userID = request()->user(); echo $userID; }

Comment: Thanks yoeunes this works - apologies for syntax error I thought it required method parameters. This still requires repetition in the methods so doesn't achieve what you suggested via constructor. Any ideas why this is failing for me?

Comment: did you try this : ` $this->userID = auth()->id(); // or auth()->user()->id`

Comment: Yes tried both as suggested:
`private $data;
 private $userID;
        
    function __construct()
{    
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
       if (!auth()->check()) {
          return redirect('/login');
       }

       //$this->userID = auth()->id(); 
       $this->userID = auth()->user()->id;

        return $next($request);
    });

}`
Called via $this->userID and using use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: @pfeatherstone see my updated answer, add a `__get` in the base controller, after that goto your mean controller and call it like this : `$this->user`, hope this work for you

Comment: I've added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; into controller.php - can't check if it is working as caused issues in other methods due to no longer using use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; - is there a way to use facade in base? Thanks for help here.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
function __construct() {
   $this->userID = Auth::user()?Auth::user()->id:null;
}

OR

public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
         $this->userID = Auth::user()->id;
         return $next($request);
     });
}
```